# How to concatenate multiple selected sheets from many XL spredhseets

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm relatively new to python and pandas and I face the following problem: I have 20+ spreadsheets with multiple sheets. I'd like to concatenate the second sheet from each spreadsheet into a single spreadsheet. I'm using the below code, which works to the point that it creates a list of sheets but doesn't concatenate them correctly, the combined file has the only sheet from the first file. Each sheet has the same header row and the same structure.

Any help would be appreciated. The code I'm using is below:

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Site_Users")

extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


#combine all files in the list
xl_list=[]
for f in all_filenames:
    df=pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 1)
    xl_list.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(xl_list, ignore_index = True)

combined.to_excel( "combined.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Try adding sort=False to your pd concat. The only other thing I can think of is that your headers don't match.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice , sort=False, didn't resolve the issue. The headers are identical also. Thanks for responding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Working under the assumption that you have a list of df's, try adding axis=0 to your concat.

i.e.

```
combined = pd.concat(xl_list, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Thank you @Garlomi, I think axis is set as default to 0 so it didn't help but I found the problem. The code is actually correct, but there were below each row with data there were around 300 rows which didn't have data but for some reason were added to in between concatenated rows with data. I looked closely at data frames in my list and noticed 400+ rows while on the sheet I could only see 10 or so. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop on this. I found the answer. The code was correct but there was number of rows which looked empty but they had formulas in them, which for the code looked like not empty cells, so it was adding those rows to the combined sheet. Because of this I missed the added rows as they were 400 rows below empty rows.